# Making my laptop display work with my desktop

Tags: display

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. 
I have a broken old Dell Latitude D620 laptop and the display of that laptop is fully functioning. I am wondering if I somehow make it work with my desktop computer.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

1. Take the LCD panel out of the laptop casing. The panel should have a label on the back of it with identifying information (model number or serial number).
   This is an example of a label: [On Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Convert-a-Laptop-LCD-into-an-External-Monit/step7/Buying-the-LCD-controller-board/)
2. Go on ebay/google and search for a ***controller board kit*** for the model number that you found on the label.
   This is an example of a controller board kit: [On Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/LCD-Controller-Board-DIY-Kit-RTMC1B-VGA-Turn-a-Laptop-LCD-to-a-Desktop-Monitor-/110907056867)

The kit consists of:

- The LCD controller (with VGA/DVI input)
- An LCD power supply for that specific LCD panel
- Buttons to turn the LCD panel on/off

Dont be spooked if you did not find anything online. Even if you did everything correctly, there is a chance that a controller kit for your panel does not exist.

Best of luck!